# Change model in CreateView dependending on user in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to change the model of a createview dependending on the user. The view class is as follow:

```
class SubirCasoView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login')
    template_name = 'casos/crear-caso.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('casos_app:update-caso')

  def get_form_class(self):
    current_user = self.request.user
    if current_user.especialidad == 'Reumatología':
        self.form_class = CasoReumaForm
    else:
        self.form_class = CasoDermaForm
    
    return self.form_class
    
  def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
    if 'borrador' == self.request.POST:
        publicar = False
        self.object = form.save()
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        '''for each in self.cleaned_data['images_description']:
            ImageDescriptionDerma.objects.create(file=each, caso=self.object)
        for each in self.cleaned_data['images_evolucion']:
            ImageEvolucionDerma.objects.create(file=each, caso=self.object)'''
    else:
        publicar = True
        self.object = form.save()
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        '''for each in self.cleaned_data['images_description']:
            ImageDescriptionDerma.objects.create(file=each, caso=self.object)
        for each in self.cleaned_data['images_evolucion']:
            ImageEvolucionDerma.objects.create(file=each, caso=self.object)'''
        
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

What I was trying to do is something similar to the function 'get_form_class' but with model. I have try it with 'get_object' function but seems not to work. My idea is to do something like:

```
def function_name(self):
        current_user = self.request.user
        if current_user.especialidad == 'Reumatología':
            self.model = CasoReuma
        else:
            self.model = CasoDerma
        
        return self.model
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **init** method to do this.

```
class SubirCasoView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        current_user = self.request.user
        if current_user.especialidad == 'Reumatología':
            self.model = CasoReuma
        else:
            self.model = CasoDerma
```

Comment: Wouldn't this set an instance attribute while model is a class attribute? Or does it not matter?

Comment: At the end I found another solution, just changing the model in the form model. As I am using two different forms depending on the user, I have changed the model in the form and it seems to save correctly.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I found a solution using the model on the form. I have selected diferent forms depending on user so I have changed the forms as this:

```
class CasoReumaForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""CasoReumaForm definition."""

# TODO: Define form fields here

tipo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CASO_REUMA, widget=forms.RadioSelect, label='Tipo de caso')
title = forms.CharField(label='Título', required=True)
description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Texto', required=True)

diagnostico = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Texto', required=True)
images_description = MultiImageField(min_num=1, max_num=3 )
images_evolucion = MultiImageField(min_num=1, max_num=2 )

evolucion = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Texto', required=True)

conclusiones = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Texto', required=True)

class Meta:
    model = CasoReuma
    fields = [
        'tipo',
        'title',
        'description',
        'diagnostico',
        'evolucion',
        'conclusiones',
        'slide',
    ]

def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(CasoReumaForm, self).save(commit)
    for each in self.cleaned_data['images_description']:
        ImageDescriptionReuma.objects.create(file=each, caso=instance)
    for each in self.cleaned_data['images_evolucion']:
        ImageEvolucionReuma.objects.create(file=each, caso=instance)

    return instance

class CasoDermaForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""CasoDermaForm definition."""

# TODO: Define form fields here

tipo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CASO_DERMA, widget=forms.RadioSelect, label='Tipo de caso')
title = forms.CharField(label='Título', required=True)
description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Texto', required=True)
images_description = MultiImageField(min_num=1, max_num=3 )
images_evolucion = MultiImageField(min_num=1, max_num=2 )
diagnostico = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Texto', required=True)
evolucion = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Texto', required=True)
conclusiones = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Texto', required=True)


class Meta:
    model = CasoDerma
    fields = [
        'tipo',
        'title',
        'description',
        'diagnostico',
        'evolucion',
        'conclusiones',
        'slide',
    ]

def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(CasoDermaForm, self).save(commit)
    for each in self.cleaned_data['images_description']:
        ImageDescriptionDerma.objects.create(file=each, caso=instance)
    for each in self.cleaned_data['images_evolucion']:
        ImageEvolucionDerma.objects.create(file=each, caso=instance)

    return instance
```